# Jenkins doesn't start by using "--group-add docker"

Tags: macos, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, docker-for-mac

To solve this, I read [How to setup Jenkins under macOS with Docker daemon access](https://superuser.com/questions/1270401/how-to-setup-jenkins-under-macos-with-docker-daemon-access) that `--group-add docker` might help.

So, while running the `docker run` with `--group-add docker`, I'll seeing following error.

Note: without `--group-add docker` it works fine, but other permission errors are seen in the Jenkins Pipeline.

```
$ docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name myjenkins2 jenkins/jenkins:2.89.4 --group-add docker
Running from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Mar 11, 2019 9:37:35 PM Main deleteWinstoneTempContents
WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file /tmp/winstone/jenkins.war
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at Main._main(Main.java:294)
    at Main.main(Main.java:132)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized option: --group-add
    at winstone.cmdline.CmdLineParser.parse(CmdLineParser.java:53)
    at winstone.Launcher.getArgsFromCommandLine(Launcher.java:363)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:334)
    ... 6 more
```

Background :

I was trying to solve the following error seen while running a docker command inside Jenkins Pipeline

```
+ whoami
jenkins
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker ps
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

Comment: You need to pass `--group-add docker` to the docker command. You've added it to the end of your command so its going to Jenkins which doesn't have that option

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  --group-add docker --name myjenkins2 jenkins/jenkins:2.89.4
```